# Symfony2. Create service for set cookies and redirecting

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I've next task: forbid create new message more per 1 minute. So logic is next. When user submit form, cookie is created with lifetime 60 sec. Then when user try to submit again I   check if cookie exist. If true - redirect user to main page. If false - create message, persist into database, creat cookie. So I create next Action in my controller:

```
namespace Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Entity\Message;
use Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Form\MessageType;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
...
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $message = new Message();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($message);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $valueOfCookiePerMinute = $request->cookies->get('perMinute');
            if ($valueOfCookieName) {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('message'));
            }
            else {
                $cookie = new Cookie('perMinute', 'CookieIsAlreadyExist', time() + 60);
                $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('message'));
                $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();

                return $response;
            }
        }
...
}
```

But I think it is fat controller. I think it can be implement service for this part of code:

```
$valueOfCookiePerMinute = $request->cookies->get('perMinute');

if ($valueOfCookieName) {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('message'));
            }
            else {
                $cookie = new Cookie('perMinute', 'CookieIsAlreadyExist', time() + 60);
                $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('message'));
                $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();

                return $response;
            }
```

But it is difficult for me imlement such service. I can't understand how I can do it/ 
Please help me to implement and understand it
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You're right, your controller should be a facade so this is a good idea to set this code in a service.

First, create a class:

```
// Messaging/MessageTimer.php

namespace Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Messaging;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class MessageTimer implements MessageTimerInterface
{
    /**
     * The database object manager.
     *
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * The router.
     *
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry The manager registry.
     */
    public function __construct(
        ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry,
        RouterInterface $router
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $managerRegistry->getManager();
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function processRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $valueOfCookiePerMinute = $request->cookies->get('perMinute');

        if ($valueOfCookieName) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('message'));
        } else {
            $cookie = new Cookie('perMinute', 'CookieIsAlreadyExist', time() + 60);
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('message'));
            $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
            $this->objectManager->persist($message);
            $this->objectManager->flush();

            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see we use an interface to have use low coupling (you will be able to replace the implentation of this class and so of the service easily). This is essential to use the dependency injection to its full potential!

```
// Messaging/MessageTimerInterface.php

namespace Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Messaging;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

interface MessageTimerInterface
{
    /**
     * Process a request.
     *
     * @param Request $request The request.
     */
    public function processRequest(Request $request);
}
```

Then, you have to declare a service on this class:

```
# Resources/config/services.yml

parameters:
    your_own.message_timer.class: Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Messaging\MessageTimer

services:
    your_own.message_timer:
        class: %your_own.message_timer.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine, @router]
```

Finally, you only have to use it like that in your controller:

```
namespace Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Entity\Message;
use Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Form\MessageType;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $message = new Message();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($message);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return $this->get('your_own.message_timer').processRequest($request);
        }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi! I use your code and get error: `Attempted to call method "generateUrl" on class "Faster\Bundle\MessageBundle\Messaging\MessageTimer".` Can you help check it?

Comment: This should be fixed now. Tell me if there is still a problem. I don't have the time to test it in a real app sorry.